# time complexity for list stl with sort in a while loop

Tags: c++, stl

What is time complexity for following code  :

```
while(!list.empty()) {
    list.sort();
    a = list.front();
    list.pop_front(); 
    b = list.front();
    list.pop_front();
    /** do something calculations*/
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Each invocation of `list.sort()` has O(N log N) complexity<sup>1</sup>. It might be faster for a sorted list--but then again, it could also be slower (the standard doesn't guarantee anything in either direction for this case). It's typically implemented as a merge sort, which usually isn't affected much (if at all) by pre-existing order.

In this case, you're invoking it O(N) times, so your overall complexity is O(N<sup>2</sup> log N).

As already noted in the comments, as long as you only remove items from the front of the list, the list will remain sorted, so there's no need to re-sort at each iteration.

In addition, I'd note that if you're only removing elements from the beginning, you might want to consider using a `std::deque` instead of `std::list`. Although you'll get the same computational complexity either way, there's a good chance you'll see a substantial improvement in real-life speed moving from a `list` to a `deque`. You may not be able to substitute a `deque` for a `list` in your case (e.g., `deque` doesn't provide the same iterator stability that `list` does), but in some cases it can be done.

---

1. In case you care, the precise wording from the standard (§[list.ops]/32) is: "*Complexity*: Approximately *N log N* comparisons, where `N == size()`."

Comment: It's worth considering that switching to `std::sort` sacrifices a few guaranties. `std::list::sort` preserves all iterators and pointers/references to elements, so for some applications switching might not be possible. Edit : There aren't many real world use cases for `std::list` anymore, but a requirement to always preserve iterators is the basis for most of them in my experience. So it's likely to be an obstacle (if `std::list` was the right choice in the first place).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Yup--might also depend on `std::list.sort()` being stable, in which case you'd need to use `std::stable_sort` instead of `std::sort` if you switched to a `deque`.

Comment: Thanks, I am also pushing elements into the list after calculations so thats y i need to sort it each time to get top 2 least elements.

Is there a better approach to achieve it via another container or logic?

Comment: To be able to add arbitrary elements, then retrieve the N largest (or smallest, depending on the sorting order you choose) you probably want a priority queue. Even with a list, if you're only inserting a few elements, inserting them in order may be faster than inserting then sorting.